# How to use Tensorflow's AdamOptimizer without built-in decaying learning rate?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

As far as I know, the Adam implementation of Tensorflow decay the learning rate as follow:

```
lr = (lr_t * math_ops.sqrt(1 - beta2_power) / (1 - beta1_power))
```

However, I am trying to manually manipulate the learning rate before feeding into the optimiser and I want to have the learning rate in the optimiser untouched.

Is there a way to keep the learning rate fixed? Do I have to write a new Optimiser for it?

Comment: There are many other [optimizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train) in TensorFlow. [`GradientDescentOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer) seems to be the base SGD algorithm, with no changes to the learning rate. Perhaps you would like to specify the manipulation that you wish to perform over the learning rate.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the learning rate is the main feature of Adam. You can't disable it. The optimizer that is closest to "Adam without learning rate adaptation" that is available in TF as of 1.7 is probably [MomentumOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/api_docs/python/tf/train/MomentumOptimizer).